# Identify column-level dependencies between databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, dependencies

Is there a way to identify column-level dependencies within and between databases? I'd like to generate a report of all columns in a database that are unused by anything (views, procs, UDFs).

e.g.

In database 'DB1', there is a table with a column called 'col1'. How do I determine if 'col1' is being used by procs, views or UDFs in either database 'DB1' or a second database 'DB2'?

Thank you

Comment: Answers to this question may vary by platform. Please identify which version/edition of SQL you are interested in.

Comment: Part of the problem is a column may be unused in DB1 and DB2, but used by some other downstream process you're not aware of, and deleting it may break that.  It's safer to rename the column and see if anyone screams.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id), m.*
  FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES m
 WHERE m.definition LIKE N'%my_column_name%'
```

`SYSCOMMENTS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines` have nvarchar(4000) columns. So if "my_column_name" is used at position 3998, it won't be found. SYSCOMMENTS does have multiple lines, but ROUTINES truncates.

But that won't be any help for `SELECT *` situations, because the column name won't be in text.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only col1, db1, and db2, you can script out the objects in db1 and db2 and search for references to col1.

Comment: It's only two databases to search, but there are a large number of columns to check. Original DB had an import from an external system that did not discriminate the actual columns needed for the system; it just brought them all in so there are many that are unnecessary.